# Extra quotes around JSON string values parsed using javax.json.stream.JsonParser and Java streams

Tags: java, json, java-stream

I'm parsing some JSON received from a REST service call using Java streams `JsonParser.getObjectStream()`, and filtering for particular values, but was never getting a match where I was expecting one. Digging deeper, I found that the string values being returned containing extra double-quotes at the beginning and end.

Here's some code to illustrate. First I show the "direct" method of getting values, then the streams method.

```java
package com.company.jsonptest;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;

public class GetStringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Direct...");
        JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(json));
        parser.next();
        JsonObject jsonObject = parser.getObject().asJsonObject();
        String username = jsonObject.getString("firstname");
        String name = jsonObject.getString("lastname");
        System.out.println("firstname: " + username);
        System.out.println("lastname: " + name);

        System.out.println("Streams...");
        JsonParser parser2 = Json.createParser(new StringReader(json));
        parser2.next();
        parser2.getObjectStream().forEach(entry -> {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue().toString();
            String type = entry.getValue().getValueType().toString();
            System.out.println(key + ": " + value + " (" + type + ")");
        });
    }

    private static String json = "{\n"
        + "  \"firstname\": \"John\",\n"
        + "  \"lastname\": \"Smith\"\n"
        + "}";
}
```

Here's the output. Notice the extra quotes. I've included the JsonValue type as an extra check.

```
Direct...
firstname: John
lastname: Smith

Streams...
firstname: "John" (STRING)
lastname: "Smith" (STRING)
```

Is there a way to get around this, apart from adding an extra step to strip off the quotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `getObjectStream()` just iterates the elements as `JsonValue`s, which loose the typing methods that `JsonObject` has in your first approach. The big difference is that you use `toString()` (which just returns the json "thing" behind the `:`) instead of `getString()` (which interprets that "thing" as a String).

In order to get this info (and the methods like `getString()`) back, you have to cast the `JsonValue` to a `JsonString`

```
String value = ((JsonString) entry.getValue()).getString();
```

This will return the values without quotes.

---

See this Javadoc for an example where they cast an element they search for to `JsonArray`:

https://static.javadoc.io/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.1.0-M1/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html

Comment: If only JsonValue had an asString() method to avoid casting, in the same way it has asObject() and asArray() methods, but this will do the trick... thanks!

Comment: This needed approach was not an obvious one! You are a saint